# Change button bgcolor depends on props

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I want to change the background color of a button based on the props. Assume that I have 4 different names of background colors; primary, secondary, info, and warning. I inspect the code in chrome but no background show:

[image]

This what I did:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Button } from "../assets/styles/GlobalStyles";

const Navbar = () => {
  const [button, setButton] = useState(true);

  return (
    <>
      {button ? (
        <NavBtnLink to="/">
          <Button primary>SIGN UP</Button>
        </NavBtnLink>
      ) : (
        <NavBtnLink to="/">
          <Button secondary>SIGN UP</Button>
        </NavBtnLink>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

**GlobalStyles.js (Button)**

```
export const Button = styled.button`
  padding: 8px 20px;
  background-color: ${({ primary, secondary }) =>
    primary ? ("#007bff" ? secondary : "#242424") : "transparent"};
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;

  &:hover {
  }
`;
```

Comment: Could you add `Button` component's code?

Comment: Check my code, it is added.

Comment: ("#007bff" ? secondary : "#242424") is always truthy...

Comment: Awesome! It works! Can you help me how to fix this one? I have a problem in concatenate. transform: scale(${({ click }) => (click ? 0 : 1))});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `background-color`s condition and try this:

```
 background-color: ${({ primary, secondary }) =>
    primary ? "#007bff" : secondary ? "#242424" : "transparent"};
```

[image: Edit eager-surf-51zmo]

Comment: Awesome! It works! Can you help me how to fix this one? I have a problem in concatenate. transform: scale(`${({ click }) => (click ? 0 : 1))}`);

Comment: @J.Wujeck Try: `transform: ${({ click }) => (click ? "scale(0)" : "scale(1)")};` Please check the codesandbox again. Updated! :)